# Set_item is not a part of dataRow

Tags: vb.net

I have a function in vb and i am upgrading the project from 1.1 framework to 4.0
it is giving error Set_item is not a member of datarow

```
Public Function CreateRow(ByVal [Text] As String, ByVal Value As String, ByVal dt As DataTable) As DataRow
            Dim row2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            row2.set_Item(0, [Text])
            row2.set_Item(1, Value)
            Return row2
        End Function
```

Comment: Try `row2.Item(0) = [Text]`

Comment: Welcome....good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following, SetField. SetField(Of T)(x, value) where x is either the ordinal position or the column name in the DataTable.

```
Public Function CreateRow(ByVal [Text] As String, ByVal Value As String, ByVal dt As DataTable) As DataRow
    Dim row2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    row2.SetField(Of String)(0, [Text])
    row2.SetField(Of String)(1, Value)
    Return row2
End Function
```

Comment: Although a good solution, using the DataRowExtention class is unecessary (SetField). When you do this is creates unnecessary overhead especially when you don't need the library. What happens is the metadata loader will store this dll in memory adding no value. Also using SetField creates more unboxing problems. It internally invokes a generic method that validates the parameter and then uses a generic method to unbox the object inside the DataTable, there's no value to this at this point when you can directly change the value without all of this.